# Unable to use \systeme with math expressions

Tags: math-mode, systeme

I want to use `\systeme` for a system of two equations but I find out that I cannot use math expressions such as `ln{n}`, `n^2` etc.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{systeme}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \systeme{
  c_1 ln{n} =  \frac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = \frac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = 5
  }
  \quad
  some text
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
! L'indice n'est pas un nombre entier !.
<argument> ...indice n'est pas un nombre entier !}
```

This is what I want to get:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The first equation is not a linear equation in x, y, z. What are you trying to obtain?

Comment: I edited the question, now you can see

Comment: Why don't you use the `cases` environment, possibly with an `aligned` environment inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments that this may not be the right tool for the task. If you *really* need to use it, you need to make the "variables" "known" to `systeme`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{systeme}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \systeme[\ln n]{
  \ln n=  \frac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = \frac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = 5
  }
  \quad
  \text{some text}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \systeme*[\ln n]{
  \ln n=  \frac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = \frac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = 5
  }
  \quad
  \text{some text}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An arguably somewhat more appropriate use of `systeme` could be

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{systeme}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \systeme{
  w=  \frac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = \frac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = 5
  }
  \quad
  \text{where}~w=\ln n
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Needless to mention that the last two equations contradict each other.